# Convert DER encoded certifcate to PGP file

Tags: certificate, gnupg, openssl, ssl-certificate

I have `company.cer` file which is a DER encoded certificate which I received from someone. I need to convert this file to a PGP file so that I can use

```
gpg --import <key>
```

How can I do this?
I am able to convert the DER encoded certificate to a PEM file with

```
openssl x509 -in company.cer -inform der -outform pem -out company.pem
```

Comment: You can't. A certificate is binary data signed by a CA. Any modification e.g. conversion invalidates the signature and makes it useless. X.509 and PGP/GnuPG are separate worlds that can't interact. The only thing you can do is to use the underlying cryptographic keys and reuse them in GPG: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44265262/150978

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. The problem isn't that the file is in binary DER versus Base64'd DER (aka "PEM") – the problem is that an X.509 certificate is fundamentally different from a PGP certificate, and likewise the S/MIME message format is completely incompatible with PGP or PGP/MIME formats.

Although it's true that both use the same basic algorithms (e.g. the same kind of RSA parameters), the problem is all the extra metadata that both X.509 and PGP have around it. Translating one format to another will produce a certificate that doesn't actually certify anything. (Both kinds of certificates contain a digital signature of their metadata, which is impossible to preserve during the conversion.)

But more importantly, if the person gave you an X.509 certificate for use with S/MIME, then either they plan on sending you S/MIME signed messages (which your PGP software won't be able to verify anyway), or they expect to receive S/MIME encrypted messages from you (and won't be able to read a PGP-encrypted message even if you do send them one).

Maybe you're looking for `gpgsm`, which *is* an S/MIME and X.509 toolkit?

Comment: If you write English text using Cyrillic letters, that won't result in Russian text – it'll still be English text, only incomprehensible to most readers.